# FFMPEG encoding with Intel Quick Sync, throwing "Access violation reading location "

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am using FFMPEG `ffmpeg-20150610-git-913685f`, from [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/shared/).

Using this library, I setup a application that captures UYVY frames from my frame grabber and encodes/muxes them to an MP4 file, using libx264. Works without issues.

Now, I wanted to try to enabling Intel Quick Sync, so I changed the encoder.

```
// old (libx264)
//AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
// new (Intel Quick Sync)
AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_qsv");
```

It finds the encoder ok. However, at the time of encoding a frame, I get the following exception.

> Unhandled exception at 0x000000005D4DDC9E (avcodec-56.dll) in
>   MedXChangeDecLinkTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x0000000000000048.

The exact API call is:

```
avcodec_encode_video2(_internals->videoStream.stream->codec, &pkt, _internals->videoStream.frame, &got_packet);
```

Is there more I need to do? I noticed that there was a commit that added some additional pixel formats for QSV [here](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2015-February/086560.html). Do I have to do something differently, compared to how things were done with libx264?

**UPDATE**: I also just realized that I am getting an error on the stdout.

```
[h264_qsv @ 000000c7e6d8e680] Specified pixel format yuv420p is invalid or not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that QSV requires NV12. Converted my source video and it works!

Usually, encoders specify the formats they accept, and qsv listed YUV420p, but it was wrong!